# Expectation value with series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

> (a) Show $P(X=x)=p(1-p)^x$, $x=0, 1, 2, ...$ defines a probability
>   distribution.
>
> (b) Show $E(X)=\frac{1-p}{p}$

I've done (a) but have trouble with (b). Since expectation is the sum of every $x$ multiplied by its corresponding $P(X=x)$, I suppose that $E(X)$ would be such a series:

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty p(1-p)^xx$$

If I am right, how do I calculate this sum? If not, what's the correct solution?

Comment: Read more on the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression for the expectation is right. The $x=0$ term can be omitted, so
$$E(X)=p(1-p)\left[1+2(1-p)+3(1-p)^2+4(1-p)^3+\cdots\right].$$
 Note that $1+2t+3t^2+4t^3+\cdots$ is the derivative of $1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+\cdots$, that is, of $\frac{1}{1-t}$. This derivative  is $\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$. Set $t=1-p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it the only way to solve that problem i.e. is there a more simple solution? - this was in a more or less HS level textbook. I understand your solution, though, but writing $1+t+t^2+t^3$ as $\frac{1}{1-t}$ was something new to me - how did you know that you can write it like that? Is there a name for it? And I presume that, in general, $t$ must be between -1 and 1, non-inclusive, right?

Comment: Yes, $1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$ is the Taylor-Maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{1-t}$, and it is valid only when $|t|\lt 1$. You probably first met it in school as the sum of an infinite geometric series. There are many other ways of summing the infinite series $1+2t+3t^2+4t^3+\cdots$. For example let the sum be $S$. Then $ts=t+2t^2+3t^3+\cdots$ so subtracting we get $(1-t)S=1+t+t^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-t}$. Divide both sides by $1-t$. We get $S=1/(1-t)^2$.  There are also nice ways to find the expectation by conditioning on what happens on the first trial. This bypasses series sums.

Comment: Taylor-Maclaurin series for what expression should I use for series like $1^2+2^2t+3^2t^2+4^2t^3+\cdots$ ? I ask because the next part of this exercise (which I didn't paste here) is about calculating variance - I've tried using a similar approach but I need to somehow calculate $E(X^2)$.

Comment: It is easier to find $E(X(X-1))$ and add $E(X)$. Note that the second derivative of $\frac{1}{1-t}$ is $(2)(1)+(3)(2)t+(4)(3)t^2+(5)(4)t^3+\cdots$, close to what you need. Or else differentiate $\frac{1}{1-t}$, multiply by $t$, differentiate again. Hard to put the full details in a comment. If you run into trouble, post a question, someone will probably answer quickly.